# Different behavior of app in release build Android

Tags: android, migration, release, androidx

I have recently migrated my project to androidx. I am observing a very weird UI behavior in my debug and release builds. There are multiple glitches in the UI when I use the release build i.e create an apk. For example, I have a button on the toolbar which appears/disappears based on a value pragmatically. another example is population of my recycler view etc. These work fine in the debug mode. But in release mode if switch between the orientations, it works fine.

There is no code which relies on orientation change. But somehow there is this behavior only in release mode (signed apk). Iam not sure if this is because of the migration or something that I am missing in the progaurd rules. I am not able to wrap my head around this. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is my build variation

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '-FLDEBUG'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"false"]
            ext.enableCrashlytics=false
        }
        release {
            versionNameSuffix '-FLalpha'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with proguard / r8 configuration if it's just in release mode. You should debug this in the debug build with `minifyEnabled true` for the debug build.

Comment: @Froyo Thanks for responding. I have added my build variation in the edit as I have it. Do you think any of this could be causing the isse?

Comment: It's not possible to debug unless there's some log of the crash / issue.

Comment: @Froyo Its not giving me a crash. Just the UI issues which work fine when I switch between orientations :(

Comment: Is it possible to get more details about this UI issue?

Comment: i am not sure how I can get a log since this only happens when I create an apk and test run it on my device. For example, my recyclerview populates but does not show up until I switch from portrait ->landscape->portrait. Other is the options menu on toolbar, same behaviour is seen. Basically, the views appear only when I switch orientations. This does not happen in debug mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211224/discussion-between-froyo-and-pooja-gaonkar).